# Facilitate High availability cluster(HAC) in Java

Tags: java, networking, udp, udpclient

For my class project I have the following problem. I am able to receive client information and re-send the info to the respective client. However, I am not being able to send every clients' info to every other client (Broadcast?). I also need to implement the given functions. Any help would be appreciated.

The goal is to design and implement a simple application layer protocol over UDP to
facilitate High Availability Cluster (HAC). HAC has a set of mechanism to detect failovers,
network/node failure etc. in order to re-route the traffic to the available systems. In this project
you will not be working on the questions like how to perform consistent failover, or high
availability distributed hypervisor. However, your task is to design and implement a protocol to
maintain the up-node information throughout the cluster.
Your designed protocol should perform the following functions:

a) To detect node failure periodically

b) To inform the other nodes in the network about the failure (peering option)

c) To be able to detect when the failed node comes back to life

d) To inform other nodes about the availability of new node

Client Class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class UDPClient 
{
    DatagramSocket Socket;

    public UDPClient() 
    {

    }

    public void createAndListenSocket() throws ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException 
    {
        try 
        {
            Socket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];
            String sentence = "Client 1 is up";
            byte[] data = sentence.getBytes();
            boolean flag = true; 
            CreatePacket packet = new CreatePacket(data, flag, data.length);

         while(true)
         {            
            //Serialize to send          
             Random rnd = new Random();
             int timeout = rnd.nextInt(30);
             Thread.sleep(timeout*1000); 

            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
            out.writeObject(packet);
            out.close();
            buffer.close();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer.toByteArray(), buffer.size(), IPAddress, 9876);
            Socket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("Message sent from client");           

            //Deserialize and receive packet from server
            DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
            Socket.receive(incomingPacket);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(incomingPacket.getData());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            Object receivedPacket = in.readObject();
            in.close();

            InetAddress IPAddress1 = incomingPacket.getAddress();
            int port = incomingPacket.getPort();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Response from server: ");
            System.out.println("Message : " + receivedPacket.toString());
            System.out.println("Client IP: "+ IPAddress1.getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("Client port: "+ port);                       
         }           
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        UDPClient client = new UDPClient();
        client.createAndListenSocket(); 
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
public class UDPServer 
{
    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    public UDPServer() 
    {

    }
    public void createAndListenSocket() throws ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        try 
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
            byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024];

            while (true) 
            {

                DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
                socket.receive(incomingPacket);
                CreatePacket toSendPacket = new CreatePacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
                ArrayList <CreatePacket> clients = new ArrayList<CreatePacket>(4);

               ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(incomingPacket.getData());
               ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
               Object receivedPacket = in.readObject();
               in.close();

               clients.add(toSendPacket); 

               InetAddress IPAddress = incomingPacket.getAddress();
               int port = incomingPacket.getPort();

               System.out.println(); 
               System.out.println("" + receivedPacket.toString());
               System.out.println("Client IP: "+ IPAddress.getHostAddress());
               System.out.println("Client port: "+ port);

               DatagramPacket replyPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length, IPAddress, port);
               Thread.sleep(10*1000);
                socket.send(replyPacket);
                //socket.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException i) 
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        UDPServer server = new UDPServer();
        server.createAndListenSocket();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code describing what you tried so far and where the problem is? Do not expect people here to do your homework...

Comment: I used client-server implementation for this problem. What i want to do is that Server to listen to the availability of all the clients, and
generate the packet with all clients’ availability and forward it to all clients.
Server considers a client dead, if it does not hear anything from any client till 30 seconds.However, a client can anytime come back and send its availability to Server.
Right now, my server updates only the specific client that sends its update, not all clients in the network.

Comment: I am not familiar with broadcasting and don't know if its relevant for this problem but any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want
1 - client to send message to server if it is up/alive
2 - and for server to send some message to all client if it receives signal right?

I am not sure but you can try this,
InetAddress IPAddress = incomingPacket.getAddress();
int port = incomingPacket.getPort();
as you are getting IP address of one client you can store address of all clients on server side which are up/alive in a List or array. Then if you receives signal to server use that list to send respond.
You will need to update list according to up/alive clients.